# Python Превратить столбец DF из json в отдельный DF

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Всем привет, в файле CSV один из столбцов записан в формате jsonl, подскажите пожалуйста, как превратить его в удобоваримый формат.

Пример:

| date | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"ad_type":"banner","placement":"a","view_index":1,} |
| 2 | {"ad_type":"banner","placement":"b","view_index":1,} |

Нужно:

| date | ad_type | placment | view_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banner | a | 1 |
| 2 | banner | b | 1 |

Comment: можно сделать apply(json.loads) если речь о pandas.DataFrame. Точнее только если представите данные. Иначе как пальцем в небо

Comment: Предоставьте пример данных (только не в виде скриншота, а в виде файла или текста).

Comment: Добавил таблицу.

Comment: @Namerek да, речь идет о pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: @Namerek добавил json.loads, и теперь у меня есть список словарей. Пытаюсь преобразовать его в DataFrame с помощью: for val in list: df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([val]), ignore_index = True), но ничего не выходит, видимо из за размера списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.csv`

```
date;json
1;{"ad_type":"banner","placement":"a","view_index":1,}
2;{"ad_type":"banner","placement":"a","view_index":1,}
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')

result = df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        map(
            json.loads,
            map(
                # Не должно тут в json быть запятой
                # поэтому если она там у вас действительно есть
                # нужно ее убрать
                lambda x: x.replace(',}', '}'),
                df.pop('json').iloc
            )
        )
    )

)
```

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну или даже вот так посимпатишней будет

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')
result = df.join(
    pd.json_normalize(
        df.pop('json').apply(
            str.replace, args=(',}', '}')
        ).apply(
            json.loads
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Запятой в датасете нет, это моя опечатка. Всё заработало. Тысяча благодарностей.